# html5 websocket vs mysql query

Tags: php, html

Ive written a web chat application powered by PHP.

stats:

```
Send: 8kb/s
Recieve: 8kbp/s
```

The chat will stop server communication if the user is not active after 1 minute to prevent unnecessary server traffic.

---

**I am considering HTML5 Websockets** ( [a chat demo](http://www.spike-engine.com/samples/html5-chat) )

Instead of making perpetual asynchronous call to the server for data, HTML5 websockets waits for a send & receive byte pattern.

Could it be better to program this chat application using html5 & a server powered by C# to push and pull data from the MySQL database?

What are the compatibility limitations on html5 websockets?

Comment: If by this _"What are the compatibility limitations on html5 websockets?"_ you mean browser compatibility, [caniuse.com is very useful](http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket) for this sort of thing.

Comment: You have tagged the question with PHP instead of C#.. I don't understand how you compare websockets against mysql queries? Completely different things.

Comment: Yes i was talking about compatibility. Hmm it seems IE 8 is the latest IE browser compatible with windows xp, & windows 8 does not support websockets.

Comment: @DanFromGermany i am not comparing the languages. I am comparing the result to a solution using 2 entirely different strategies.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I am not confusing anything, i am predicting what browsers my users will be capable of using. I am producing this application for commercial use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93813/discussion-between-wooper-clooper-and-danfromgermany).

Comment: @DanFromGermany I can not tell if you are trolling or are seriously confused. please join the chat.